# Modify Codeigniter profiler to send output to db instead of display on page

Tags: codeigniter, profiler

I'd like to use CI profiler as a tool to audit an app. However, obviously in this case, I do not want the output to be displayed on the page, but rather be logged to the db.

I was thinking I could hook into profiler grab the relevant details (query, uri_string, etc.) and send that to a table in the db.

I could extend the profiler class to send data to the db, but this doesn't eliminate the output to the screen. I'd like to be able to use the profiler normally as well from time to time, so re-writing the output class isn't desirable.

Any ideas appreciated.

---

What I ended up doing was creating a library and copylasagna Profiler.php into it to modify as needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.  Add MY_Profiler.php to your **libraries/** directory (I assume you're in the 2.0+ branch; if not, lemme know):

```
<?php
class MY_Profiler extends CI_Profiler {
    public function run()
    {
        $output = parent::run();
        // log output here, and optionally return it if you do want it to display
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** And to automatically enable the profiler for each controller (add to core/MY_Controller.php):

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    }
}
// but each controller will have to extend MY_Controller, not CI_Controller...
class Somecontroller extends MY_Controller { //... }
```

Comment: Yesm, 2.0. So If I extend the profiler as in your example then hook into post_system a'la http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/151968/#915515 will it not output profiler to screen as MY_Profiler will usurp the output? Or could I extend CI_profiler directly within the hooks function? Thanks.

Comment: My example will show normal output (without the profiler information) unless you "return $output;" from the run() function.  No need for a hook unless you want a blank page.  In that case, you'd be better off just putting in an empty _output() function in your controller.

Comment: I'm confused. I added your example verbatim to my core folder, and when I add $this->output->enable_profiler(true) to a controller, the output is showing even though I'm not returning it. I was talking about hooks as a means to not have to add $this->output->enable_profiler(true) to each controller. Thanks.

Comment: Updated answer.  Dumb mistake on my part--Profiler class isn't core, but a library, so it goes in the libraries folder. *facepalm*

Comment: And an easier way of not having to extend the controller (and update your controller extensions for every class) would be to extend CI_Output (as MY_Output; this time it DOES go in the core/ folder), and enable_profiler(TRUE) in the class constructor...

Comment: Yeah I tried adding it to other folders. If I put it in the libraries folder (same one Profiler.php is in), I get a fatal error "Fatal error: Class 'CI_Profiler' not found". I'm not sure if this is due to the seemingly strange relationship between CI_Profiler/Output or the fact that I'm using PyroCMS, but no matter where I put it, I can't get it to see the CI_Profiler class in order to extend it.

Comment: The file should be... application/libraries/MY_Profiler.php. It shouldn't be under your system/ folder at all...

Comment: OK, sorry. 2 questions: 1) By extending CI_Profiler I have a way to work with the profiler output, but because I'm calling enable_profiler, the output still shows on screen even if I'm not returning $output from MY_Profiler; how can I hide it? 2) Relating to #1, public function run() in MY_Profiler never gets called, so $output is moot, no? And I apparently can't load a library via $this->load that lives outside system/application/libraries folder and can't extend CI_Profiler from library in system/application/libraries folder. Zeus help me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5020/discussion-between-landons-and-stormdrain)

Comment: This is so buggy! should be prevented!

Answer (score -2):

You can hack `core/Output` to save the `Profiler` class output to DB, or display it on the screen, or both. Just add another switch similar to `$this->enable_profiler`;

You might also want to take a look at [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/). It allows you to profile apps, write the profiles to disk, and examine them with tools later.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid modifying the core, but will keep it in mind. Thanks,

Comment: I expect you'll change it back before deploying. Even if you don't there's nothing sacred or holy about the core classes. Code is code.

Comment: True, code is indeed code; maleable and amorphous. However, it makes updating/upgrading the framework difficult if you have to track/update core files that you have modified.

Comment: In this case, I think it's OK. You don't plan on profiling the application while in production do you?