# Codeigniter profiler to send output to file instead of display on page?

Tags: codeigniter, debugging, profiler

Sorry, I do not speak English, but I have a question.

I need to save the output of $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE) into the some file.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: What you you tried to do so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138004/modify-codeigniter-profiler-to-send-output-to-db-instead-of-display-on-page) just the difference is he has logged in db.