# Access Codeigniter's profiler data?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

There's a bunch of good stuff in Codeigniter's profiler that I'd like to write to my logs, so I can then parse it out and trend things over time. I don't really care to re-write the logic or install a different profiler, but looking through Profiler.php I fear I might have to.

Question #1:
Is there a way to get at the profiler data in, say, array or object form, or is it really all mixed up with HTML?

Question #2:
If the profiler won't get me what I need, what might be a good alternative? I'm not opposed to just using the benchmark library where needed, but that's meh at best.

Comment: Sadly, even the benchmark class seems to be too "UI friendly". `"duration":"1,106.8017"`, for example, that number format isn't helping my use case. Looks like I'll be going to town.

Comment: you need to extend profiler [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138004/modify-codeigniter-profiler-to-send-output-to-db-instead-of-display-on-page)