# Codeigniter 2 profiling on all pages

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to add profiling info on all my page is a specific admin user is logged in. This way it's easy to troubleshoot stuff.

I know you can add

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

to a controller. Is there a way to enable & display profiling on every page, without adding the above to every single function in each controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You create file in core folder my_controller.php
 MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
call this MY_Controller to all controller with extend MY_Controller instead of CI_Controller

Comment: And what are the contents? I tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138004/modify-codeigniter-profiler-to-send-output-to-db-instead-of-display-on-page, but doesn't work for CI2